# Execute two commands sequentially on one line in R?

Tags: r, syntax, command

I know in shell one can do:

```
command1; command2
```

How about in R? Is there some syntax where I could combine two commands onto one line?

Comment: yes... trying it would have been so much faster than writing this question.  As I say to my students... just try stuff, muck around.  You won't break anything.

Comment: Ah - I did try it but I got an error in my second command because of the command's syntax and I had attributed it to trying to combine the two.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

try ";":

```
cat("12"); cat("13"); cat("\n")
```

Comment: For reference see [R Language Definition](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Control-structures)